# main product image is not coming on product listing. Placeholder is coming

Tags: magento-1.9, database, catalog

I have uploaded the csv for product upload in magento panel. I have multistores on magento. Csv doesn't have image path, i added the image manually. Images are coming properly on all site but on product listing page (Catalog Page), placeholder image is coming.

Please tell me what should i do

Answer (score 0):

May be your flat tables were enable for catalog, for this just go to

admin panel

`System -> Index Management` and refresh indexes

may [this tutorial](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-re-index-data-and-in-what-cases-it-is-needed.html#gref) will help you

Comment: I have done it. but still issue is same..

Comment: https://www.axcxz.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/235x299/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/placeholder/default/blank-white-page2_2.jpg

Comment: go to product edit at admin panel and there you have not selected radio button for `small_image `

Comment: This link is coming. magento has added placeholder link in his table. I am changing the thumbnail image also from panel but its not updating. Only placeholder is coming

Comment: Murtuza It's not working.